# Super confused on pagination hooks for reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm suppose to be implementing pagination for a web page.

I have two files, Pagination.jsx and usePagination.js
I have implemented what I could do so far but nothing shows up for the return on usePagination.js for currentData, next, prev, jump

I'm definetely missing some key logic here and I need someone to help me out with what I did. Any help or insight is appreciated. (Note: new to react js)

**usePagination.js :**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
export const DOTS = "...";

function usePagination(data, itemsPerPage) {

  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const maxPage = Math.ceil(data.length / itemsPerPage);

  function currentData() {
    const begin = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;
    const end = begin + itemsPerPage;
    return data.slice(begin, end);
  }

  function next() {
    setCurrentPage((currentPage) => Math.min(currentPage + 1, 
maxPage));
  }

  function prev() {
    setCurrentPage((currentPage) => Math.max(currentPage - 1, 1));
  }

  function jump(page) {
    const pageNumber = Math.max(1, page);
    setCurrentPage((currentPage) => Math.min(pageNumber, maxPage));
  }


  return [currentPage, currentData, next, prev, jump];
}


export default usePagination;
```

**Pagination.jsx :**

```
import "../css/pagination.scss";

import { ChevronLeftIcon, ChevronRightIcon } from 
"@heroicons/react/outline";
import usePagination, { DOTS } from "../hooks/usePagination";

import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

function Pagination({
  onPageChange,
  onPageSizeOptionChange,
  totalCount,
  currentPage,
  pageSize,
  pageSizeOptions,
}) {
  const paginationRange = usePagination({
    currentPage,
    totalCount,
    pageSize,
  });

  const onNext = () => {
    onPageChange(currentPage + 1);
  };

  const onPrevious = () => {
    onPageChange(currentPage - 1);
  };

  return (
    <ul
      className="wrapper"
      // Do not remove the aria-label below, it is used for Hatchways automation.
      aria-label="Blog post pagination list"
    >
      <li className="paginationItem">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="arrowButton left"
          // Do not remove the aria-label below, it is used for Hatchways automation.
          aria-label="Goto previous page"
          onClick={onPrevious}
          disabled={false} // change this line to disable a button.
        >
          <ChevronLeftIcon />
        </button>
      </li>

      {paginationRange.map((pageNumber) => {
        const key = nanoid();

        if (pageNumber === DOTS) {
          return (
            <li key={key} className="dots">
              &#8230;
            </li>
          );
        }

        return (
          <li
            key={key}
            className="paginationItem"
            aria-current="false" // change this line to highlight a current page.
          >
            <button
              type="button"
              // Do not remove the aria-label below, it is used for Hatchways automation.
              aria-label={`Goto page ${pageNumber}`}
              onClick={() => onPageChange(pageNumber)}
            >
              {pageNumber}
            </button>
          </li>
        );
      })}

      <li className="paginationItem">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="arrowButton right"
          // Do not remove the aria-label below, it is used for Hatchways automation.
          aria-label="Goto next page"
          onClick={onNext}
          disabled={false} // change this line to disable a button.
        >
          <ChevronRightIcon />
        </button>
      </li>

      <select
        className="paginationSelector"
        // Do not remove the aria-label below, it is used for Hatchways automation.
        aria-label="Select page size"
        value={pageSize}
        onChange={(e) => {
          onPageSizeOptionChange(e.target.value);
        }}
      >
        {pageSizeOptions.map((size) => (
          <option key={size} defaultValue={pageSize === size} value={size}>
            {size} per page
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </ul>
  );
}

Pagination.propTypes = {
  totalCount: PropTypes.number,
  currentPage: PropTypes.number,
  pageSize: PropTypes.number,
  pageSizeOptions: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array),
  onPageChange: PropTypes.func,
  onPageSizeOptionChange: PropTypes.func,
};

Pagination.defaultProps = {
  totalCount: 0,
  currentPage: 1,
  pageSize: 1,
  pageSizeOptions: [15, 25, 50, 100],
  onPageChange: () => {},
  onPageSizeOptionChange: () => {},
};

export default Pagination;
```

Comment: In `usePagination` you return `[currentPage, currentData, next, prev, jump]`, but then when you use it, you try to get `paginationRange`. What is this `paginationRange`?

Comment: can you show how did you call the component 
because for me it's working fine